# x86_64 callback sigsegv debugging

Tags: linux, gdb, segmentation-fault

Please let me know if there is more information I need to enter. The stackexchange robot seems to think there is not enough of it here.

The below stack trace is generated as a result of a an invalid callback pointer. I'd like to understand where the callback occurred in the code. I know how to do this in MIPS, but not in Intel architecture.

I get the following backtrace on sigsegv:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000361f20cc5a in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x7f382f1e1810
(gdb)
```

When I try to disassemble I get:

```
(gdb) disassemble
No function contains program counter for selected frame.

(gdb) info reg
rax            0x7f2bf3fb8790   139826753669008
rbx            0x7f3200197520   139852726760736
rcx            0x7f3200197540   139852726760768
rdx            0x0      0
rsi            0x7f2bf3fb87b0   139826753669040
rdi            0x0      0
rbp            0x7f2bf3fb87b0   0x7f2bf3fb87b0
rsp            0x7f382f1e1810   0x7f382f1e1810
r8             0x20000  131072
r9             0x453d780        72603520
r10            0x27     39
r11            0x7f2dcbfa9ec8   139834672455368
r12            0x7f2bf3fb87b0   139826753669040
r13            0x7f3196fd2790   139850963298192
r14            0x7f2c080008c0   139827089508544
r15            0xfffffffffffffe68       -408
rip            0x361f20cc5a     0x361f20cc5a
eflags         0x10206  [ PF IF RF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

Processor information:

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2658A v3 @ 2.20GHz
```

Comment: You provided a lot of info, but forgot to ask a question.

Comment: As I stated above: I am trying to understand how to read the registers when encountering a sigsegv on a callback.
I would like to create the backtrace that led to the callback sigsegv'ing.